# How can I completely disable calls to assert()?

Tags: c++, c, assert

My code is full of calls to `assert(condition)`.
In the debug version I use `g++ -g` which triggers my assertions.
Unexpectedly, the same assertions are also triggered in my release version, the one compiled without `-g` option.

How can I completely disable my assertions at compile time? Should I explicitly define `NDEBUG` in any build I produce regardless of whether they are debug, release or anything else?

Comment: Somewhat off topic: if you want debug information, `-g` is equivalent to `-g2`. `-g3` might be a better choice, since it makes available the most symbolic information. For example, at `-g3`, symbolic #defines will be available. I've seem some toolchains choke on `-g3`, though. Also, many external libraries also depend upon `-DDEBUG` for 'debug' builds (Posix only attests to `-DNDEBUG` for 'release' builds).

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You must `#define NDEBUG` (or use the flag `-DNDEBUG` with *g++*) this will disable assert as long as it's defined before the inclusion of the assert header file.

Comment: must be before `#include <assert.h>`?

Comment: @LeiYang Seems must be add before last `#include <assert.h>`.

Comment: so its either #define NDEBUG before inclusion of assert.h or use -DNDEBUG while compiling.

Answer (score 42):

Use `#define NDEBUG`

> **7.2  Diagnostics**
>
> 1      The header deﬁnes the **assert** macro and refers to another macro,
>
> **NDEBUG**
>
> which  is not deﬁned  by `<assert.h>`. 
>   If **NDEBUG** is  deﬁned  as  a  macro  name  at  the point in the source ﬁle where  is included, the **assert** macro is deﬁned
>   simply as
>
> `#define assert(ignore) ((void)0)`
>
> The **assert** macro is redeﬁned according to the current state of **NDEBUG** each time that
>   `<assert.h>` is included.

Comment: Hi! If it is true that  when I define -DNDEBUG, still a call to assert executes something i.e.  ((void)0), is this going to spend minimum CPU cycles? I thought that was mapped simply to nothing i.e. completely NO CODE..isnt' this way?

Comment: @Abruzzo: I also thought so until now, but giving it a second thought, this would leave an empty `;` instead, which may be problematic if the `assert` is inside an `if`, for instance. I am sure that the compiler optimizes lines like `0;` away

Comment: @Abruzzo, and BTW, check whether your IDE or your build system allows you to specify a default template for a new project. Then you can have NDEBUG defined in the Release configuration of every new project

Comment: @Abruzzo What do you mean by no code?  There will be no code generated in the executable by ((void)0).  And the standard requires that assert can be used anywhere an expression with void type can be used, so just replacing it with no tokens what so ever won't work.

Comment: The compiler optimizes it out at compile time. Think of it as a NOP. Useless NOPs get removed, but this is compiler dependent. For example, compiling MIPS code, one may have assembly files in which has NOPs which stay in there to cover the branch and load delays to where it is needed to align instructions to clock cyclic boundaries or else undefined behavior.

Answer (score 13):

You can either disable assertions completely by

```
#define NDEBUG
#include <assert.h>
```

or you can set NDEBUG (via -DNDEBUG) in your makefile/build procedure depending on whether you want a productive or dev version.

Answer (score 13):

The `-g` flag doesn't affect the operation of `assert`, it just ensures that various debugging symbols are available.

Setting `NDEBUG` is the standard (as in official, ISO standard) way of disabling assertions.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, define `NDEBUG` on the command line/build system with the preprocessor/compiler option `-DNDEBUG`.

This has nothing to do with the debugging info inserted by `-g`.