# Should I do return after Assert failed?

Tags: c++, error-handling, assert

Should I:

```
void func(some* ptr)
{
    ASSERT(ptr);

    ptr->do();
}
```

or

```
void func(some* ptr)
{
    if (ptr == NULL)
    {
        ASSERT(0);
        return;
    }

    ptr->do();
}
```

P.S. the `assert` is our home-made version, not default one.
It's a no-return version and becomes `noop` in production mode.

I prefer the first one, code is simpler, shorter and no needless code here.
But with first one, I can only detect error during development mode.
Surely I should kill all the bugs during development, but if somehow untested cases happend after the production goes online, i.e. `ptr` really becomes `NULL`, then `func` is failed.

So the advantage of second part is that I can have error detect and guarantee of no crash both in development and production modes.
But the downside is that this code looks messy, and becomes needless if we would never have `ptr == NULL`.

So which way should I use?

Comment: I strongly recommend using a name other than `assert` for a non-standard variant of `assert`. Consider, for example, using `ASSERT()` or `Assert()`.  If you want the test at run-time, use a variant of the second version (wrapped in a suitable macro), with code that logs the violation of the invariant in as much detail as possible (stack backtrace?) to a suitable permanent log file from which you can get the information later.  But if you think you might have that invariant violated at runtime, you need to test for it and handle it — that's no longer a regular `assert()`.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, it's actually `ASSERT` in our project, it's my typo, truely sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check errors in production, I suggest not using something that becomes `noop` in production mode. You have to decide whether you want to save cycles in production and eliminate assertions, or leave them in and experience the slight performance hit. There is no compromise, it's either-or.

That said, you should use the first form; the second form is weird, messy, and doesn't do what you think it does. You should use a macro instead of the function so that if you do decide to switch them off not even a function call remains; a noop function call still takes time.

Finally, I have to ask: what is your reason for using a homemade `assert`? The original assert already includes the possibility of [switching it off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354314/how-to-completely-disable-assertion).

Comment: Hi: the homemade one do some log output into files, and we are using macro not function, sorry for didnt write it clearly.

Answer (score 1):

The second version doesn't actually detect errors in the production version. It returns silently, causing all sorts of hard-to-diagnose havoc. If you want to detect assert failures in production, turn asserts on in production.