# Are asserts disabled in release build?

Tags: c++, linux, g++, assert

Are asserts disabled in 'release' build?

How optional flags like `-O0`,`-O3`,`-g` of `g++` affects it's behaviour?

Comment: Have you considered consulting the the documentation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354314/how-to-completely-disable-assertion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`assert()` in the `<cassert>` header is only disabled if you define the macro `NDEBUG` prior to including the `<cassert>` header file. See also these [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert)

With gcc/g++, the easiest way to do so is to define the `NDEBUG` macro on the command line when invoking the compiler like so:

```
g++ -DNDEBUG ... other args...
```

Arguments such as optimization flags and similar flags does not disable the assert.

Answer (score 0):

From the man page:

> If the macro NDEBUG was defined at the moment `assert.h` was last
>   included, the macro assert() generates no code