# 0xc0000005 exception arises in SimplicialLLT.compute() when the program is compiled with VS 2017 with Optimization set to /O2

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, eigen, eigen3

I am compiling a C++ command line program involving **Eigen 3.3.4**, using **VS 2017 Professional edition**.

This is my program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Eigen/Dense"
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <Eigen/Eigenvalues>
#include <vector>



using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;
using Eigen::Dynamic;
using Eigen::Matrix;
using Eigen::SparseMatrix;

typedef SparseMatrix<double, Eigen::RowMajor> SpMat;

int main()
{
    try
    {
        MatrixXd mat(8, 8);

        mat << 7, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 7, 0,
            0, 4, 8, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0,
            1, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5,
            0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 9, 0,
            0, 2, 0, 0, 5, 1, 5, 0,
            2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 5,
            7, 0, 0, 9, 5, 0, 11, 0,
            0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 5, 0, 5;

        cout << mat << endl;

        Eigen::LLT<Eigen::MatrixXd> lltOfA(mat);
        cout << lltOfA.info() << endl;

        SpMat sparseMat = mat.sparseView();

        cout << "try SimplicialLLT solver" << endl;
        SimplicialLLT<SpMat, Eigen::Upper> lltSolver;
        lltSolver.compute(sparseMat);
        cout << lltSolver.info() << endl;

    }
    catch (const exception& e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is my linker option:

> /OUT:"D:\TestProjects\LLTSolver\x64\Release\LLTSolver.exe" /MANIFEST
>   /LTCG /NXCOMPAT
>   /PDB:"D:\TestProjects\LLTSolver\x64\Release\LLTSolver.pdb"
>   /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib"
>   "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib"
>   "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X64 /OPT:REF
>   /INCREMENTAL:NO
>   /PGD:"D:\TestProjects\LLTSolver\x64\Release\LLTSolver.pgd"
>   /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'"
>   /ManifestFile:"x64\Release\LLTSolver.exe.intermediate.manifest"
>   /OPT:ICF /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1

And this is my compilation option:

> /Yu"stdafx.h" /GS /GL /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl
>   /Fd"x64\Release\vc110.pdb" /D "WIN32" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D
>   "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oi /MD
>   /Fa"x64\Release\" /EHa /nologo /Fo"x64\Release\"
>   /Fp"x64\Release\LLTSolver.pch"

Here are my findings:

1. If I compile it with `Release` flag, and with no optimization(`/Od`), then the program can work well. The output can be generated when I run my program in command line
2. If I compile it with `Release` flag, and with optimization ( either `/O1` or `O/2`), then the program will crash, and it will crash in such a way that ***not even the `catch` statement can catch the exception***.

The only trace I can find, resulted from the crash, is in event viewer:

```
Faulting module name: LLTSolver.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5a6e9440
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000000d4b4
Faulting process id: 0x5004
Faulting application start time: 0x01d398b0e99f62f4
```

When I compile without the `NDEBUG` macro (gcc equivalent of `-DNDEBUG`), I will get the following message, *sometimes*; some other times, no error message at all.

```
Assertion failed: (m_outerIndex[outer+1]-m_outerIndex[outer]==0 || m_data.index(m_data.size()-1)<inner) && "Invalid ordered insertion (invalid inner index)",
```

at file

> ..\eigen\src/SparseCore/SparseMatrix.h, line 393

Not too sure whether the VS compiler optimization is to be blamed, or there is a bug in Eigen 3.3.4. How can I proceed further on this?

Comment: Add the compiler and linker options to add in the debug info into your optimized builds, then run with/attach to the debugger to see the fault and inspect the data.  Since the exception is a Windows system exception, it isn't an `exception` object.  You can catch it with `catch (...)`.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm are you sure that there are "debug infos" for the optimized build? Isn't all of the debug information has been stripped off from that build?

Comment: You can always add debug info to a build.  It can be difficult to debug an optimized build, though.

Comment: Compile without -DNDEBUG to get Eigen's assertions.

Comment: @ggael, by `-DNDEBUG` you mean [NDEBUG macro in VS 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5354352/3834)? I've tried both to include and exclude `NDEBUG`, and the results were the same. The program crashed all the same, and no extra message.

Comment: @ggael, sorry! There *is* an error message after all, let me update my question

Comment: Spooooooky... When things "work sometimes" that often suggest memory corruption or binary incompatibility. I'm going to guess here that you are mixing release and debug binaries - something MSVC doesn't support as those two use vastly different memory management routines.

Comment: @YePhIcK, I am compiling only one exe with eigen headers. No extra binaries involved. And the program crashed every single time with release build and optimization

Comment: 0xc0000005 is a segmentation fault, a debugger should be able to give you a stack trace of where it is happening...

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Do you include some weird headers? How exactly `SpMat` is defined?

Comment: @ggael, I've updated the question with a compilation and linker option, plus the header. See whether you can still reproduce the problem or not

Comment: maybe try to remove 'stdafx.h' and if you still get the error look at the backtrace in the debugger to understand what's going on.

Comment: @ggael, the error is still there after `stdafx.h` is removed. And I am not sure how I can get the error in debugger because the problem manifested itself in optimized build. BTW, do you have any luck reproducing the issue with my new updated question and setting?

Comment: I was unable to reproduce on VS2015. Have you tried a different version as well?