# How can i detour assert?

Tags: c++

I have to detour the assert function, but i don't know how to do it. I tried a few things but I don't share it here because it is garbage.
i need to change them params.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    assert(2 + 2 == 4);
    std::cout << "Execution continues past the first assert\n";
}
```

Comment: What does "detour" mean here?

Comment: `assert()` is supposed to crash the program if the assertion fails. Are you saying "how do I disable assertions?"

Comment: @tadman actually yes, i have to disable assertions from the process of injected dll.

Comment: You mean [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354314/how-to-completely-disable-assertion)? `assert()` should be disabled in non-debug builds.

Comment: Have you considered using a macro @Berkay Karatas?

Comment: @tadman nah, probly main process is works on debug mode. so seems i need to detour it for pass params.

Comment: @mix_42 i have no knowledge about macros, lemme research about it, thank you for your comment

Comment: `assert` isn't a function, but a macro. It's up to the implementation that compiled said process whether it's possible to detour assertions in another process you don't own without detouring `abort` in general. (And if you do own it, you can do better.)

Comment: Assertions shouldn't trip unless there's problems, so maybe fix those problems or change the assertions if you can.

Comment: Define `NDEBUG` when compiling. For `g++`/`clang++` add `-DNDEBUG` to the compilation command.

Comment: @chris probly you are right, your comment is the most logical. i m going to make some tests  and than will share here the result.

Comment: If you are making a release build in Visual Studio, `NDEBUG` should be defined automagically and `assert()` should do nothing.

Comment: @ThomasJager, Presumably, the OP is talking about the [Detours library](https://github.com/microsoft/Detours), which lets you redirect function calls without changing the source code.

Comment: @BerkayKaratas "_i have to disable assertions from the process of injected dll_" - You can't disable assertions made within the DLL - unless you have the source code for the dll and can recompile it in release mode. Can you describe this in more detail, by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60997981/edit) the question?  Is the assertion done inside a DLL? Is it a DLL you have the source code for? Are you compiling it in debug or release mode? .Are you trying to use the detours library chris mentioned?